# How to config redis eviction policy runtime?

Tags: redis

In the official site, it says:

> however you can reconfigure the policy at runtime while the
>   application is running

How can I achieve if I want to use `volatile-lru` policy at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the [`CONFIG SET` command](https://redis.io/commands/config-set) - for example, to set the eviction policy to 'noeviction' send this command (e.g. via redis-cli):

```
redis> CONFIG SET maxmemory-policy noeviction
```

Comment: What happens to keys with expiry time if the policy is changed to `lfu` or `noeviction`? Is that behaviour defined?

Comment: Expiry and eviction are different things... expiry happens because of the clock, whereas eviction happens under memory pressure.

Comment: What I meant was setting `maxmemory-policy` to `volatile-lru` first and then changing it to `volatile-lfu` at runtime. What happens to keys with expire time still left? Will it honor the clock or the frequency?

Comment: I'm really not sure what the behavior is in this... so I'd recommend against that :)